# sendTransaction from iPhone app

Tags: transactions, web3js, blockchain, dapps, dapp-development

How do I call sendTransaction from within an iPhone app?

I was thinking of running a web to Geth proxy where the iPhone app would call the Api exposed by the proxy which in turn calls my self hosted Geth client. Is that the right way to go? Does such proxy exist in open source?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a Geth RPC endpoint is the way to go. You can use `web3` to connect to the geth and maybe a `nginx` or `NodeJS` in front end to keep the `RPC` endpoint from public by adding some authentication mechanisms like,

1. Add SSL
2. API Keys
3. Even Oauth :)