# Is there an iOS equivalent for the Android web3j (json-rpc) library?

Tags: json-rpc, android, ios

This question ([Ethereum library for iOS/Android?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/ethereum-library-for-ios-android)) showed me the way to web3j, but I also need a similar solution for iOS.  Does anyone know of such a project?

Answer (score 4):

There is a web3 library for swift [web3swift](https://github.com/matterinc/web3swift).

Answer (score 1):

Nope, I didn't find a similar solution to communicate with a blockchain. The easiest way that I found to run a node using [Geth](https://geth.ethereum.org) and communicate with it via [JSON RPC API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC).