# How to call a deployed smart contract methods from android

Tags: solidity, truffle, web3j, android

I deployed a smart contract into my private network using truffle framework. After deployed the contract I implemented a client interface using android from android I want to call the methods of deployed contract. is it possible to call the smart contract methods using truffle? or it is possible with web3j only? with web3j can I again deploy the smart contract with solc? anybody, please give me a clarity

Answer (score 1):

I think the information [found in this thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48264/how-to-invoke-functions-of-smart-contract-from-android-phone/48268#48268) could be helpful to you.

My response was :

> Geth can be run both on Android as well as iOS. The nightly builds of the develop branch always include the Android .aar archives that you can link against an Android Studio project and the iOS framework that you can use in XCode.
>
> Since Geth does not yet feature the light client functionality (that one actually needs Ethereum global P2P protocol updates), it's quite heavyweight, but it will be the official way to run mobile DApps, and AFAIK only Geth has even a remote concept about light client support.
>
> More info can be found at [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3165/what-can-i-use-to-interact-with-the-ethereum-network-from-an-android-device?rq=1).

Another response that I think directly answers your question found in that thread is:

> You should look into web3j over at https://web3j.io/ They have a Java library that interacts with the Ethereum blockchain similar to the JavaScript web3.js library. It has an Android version as well as a vanilla Java version.

Comment: I created a wrapper class for the deployed contract using web3j commands. so how to use smart contract methods in my android app?